# How to collect denormalization type errors in serializer and return them in http response as constraint violations using API Platform?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I want to use Symfony 5.4 serializer's feature (https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-4-serializer-improvements) to collect denormalization type errors and return them as a Response with constraint violations using API Platform 2.6. How can I achieve this?

**Entity:**

```
    <?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *  collectionOperations={
 *      "get",
 *      "post",
 *  },
 *  itemOperations={
 *      "get",
 *  "put",
 *  "delete",
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Property
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="App\EntityIdGenerator")
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=12)
     */
    private string $id;


    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    public string $name;

    public function getId(): string
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

**Request to create a new property:**

```
POST /properties HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2NDE4MTU0MzQsImV4cCI6MTY3MzM1MTQzNCwicm9sZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9VU0VSIl0sInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiaG9zdEBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsImlkIjoiaUthRmp6QjZaRWNDIn0.e6PuoDFrPF4HUFE24rrkAoUMQPqvtWaGwTo-Ec4BOdo1_IyyoxIee7dIGx4fY0yvjhNwH7_XtZKYg3LPzRqusZonT4ysqHe1V7MNepSHNosyAhZNsBdZ8md-2G-MBNYowzgb3_TFlYZxWNVf2cs0R5Du18QN6xQLv0hfZjG1MVOnygzo6nP9ywTwEi7hrIt7cdXsyLdOnf_2yRFQJ4bc80-E8uYQ_HzNo7J1Cq-uwyaNlJbEHHleSEgx3xBqDccPu3DtvhRuXNwStDWgOjv8uYEYHs19zzXV4BQv93dIVMExOZ5_IysDsVGCO74kwC_T1kXFlQvuNMmHBYmCIWBpJefkyutvoBZXR1Oorij0nXZ9M96my2r6z_I-kH2KNkAdi8u3rz8k7rOfQpZrYNNtYj4t_jkNghGaXm2Syalb7XZ-XUTD24rOKYlniLY-6U14S-IyyrVl3k6iDvWDqJrqbWT8PXJqzppDnXc_qgMF309TqavpI17xH2x_KFQHW07Fg0y8NZBIK_k9hCVBPxqQOg6VbaXJFm4tu7oR1m6AAQoXGu_uVopiJz5DMrbzEZ5cTxP7Gla2OohpeLQBnOhAqf_VEjKUs9ajht_mIqs1MjECA_aJEWL62EghtjGNdhNUfUh1mss73Tstah9IKSULZkTlelRhLZ_OhCkogfWkbLU
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 19

{
  "name": null,
}
```

**Current server response:**

HTTP response code 400.

Response body:

```
{
    "@context": "/contexts/Error",
    "@type": "hydra:Error",
    "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
    "hydra:description": "The type of the \"name\" attribute must be \"string\", \"NULL\" given.",
    "trace": [
...]
```

**Desired server response:**

Http response code 422.

Response body:

```
{
    "@context": "/contexts/ConstraintViolationList",
    "@type": "ConstraintViolationList",
    "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
    "hydra:description": "name: This value cannot be omitted.",
    "violations": [
        {
            "propertyPath": "name",
            "message": "This value is cannot be omitted.",
            "code": "9ff3fdc4-b214-49db-8718-39c315e33d45"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Will leave it here if somebody is also looking. [PR](https://github.com/api-platform/docs/pull/1643) has been merged not a long time ago, it ended in 3.1.0 version. To enable this feature for all resources:

```
    defaults:
        collectDenormalizationErrors: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add an `@Assert` annotation on top of fields with your rules ?

For example I'm using DTO, and without `@Assert` I have the same output than you, but with it I have the desired one:

```
<?php

namespace App\DTO\Event;

use DateTime;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class EventPostInput
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    public string $title;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    public string $description;
}
```

And there is my entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\DTO\Event\EventPostInput;
use App\Repository\EventRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ApiResource(
    collectionOperations: [
        'post' => [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'input' => EventPostInput::class,
        ]
    ]
)]
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=EventRepository::class)
 */
class Event
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private string $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=2000)
     */
    private string $description;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).